# Merging Client/Server Side Templating Engines

Tags: javascript, templates, node.js, handlebars.js, underscore.js

I'm about to start a new project using node, backbone, underscore, and express among other things. On the views side I am using jade. I know I am going to have tons of ajax like interactions so I was going to use handlebars; however, I feel that there would be a significant amount of code duplication from my jade templates.

1. Is there a way to render the jade templates and fill in data
   straight from client side? How can I route requests directly to the
   views without filling in the data?
2. If I can't do the above it seems that I actually have a few templating engines I could use, underscore, jquery, handlebars... Is it not a waste to have all of
   those templating engines laying around? Should I just use underscore
   or jquery and not even worry about handlebars any more? Is there a
   preferred engine?
3. Is there some hybrid method where I can fill in data similarly to handlebars into my jade templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Express isn't doing any magic with jade template rendering. Simply have a look at the [public api](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#public-api) and you know how to render jade views on the client side. For routing requests on the client side you can use [page.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js) from the express author. A little bit of work and magic and you have routes working with the exact same code on the server and client side and both are rendering to jade.